Перебор списка. И сравнение его элементов

В общем подскажите как брать три элемента перебирая текстовый файл, чтобы потом проводить проверки с элементов. И пожалуйста что то не в одну строку. Ps"для людей а не для ии"


Ну показывайте, как вы перебираете, тогда можно и про три элемента что-то посоветовать.

я вот и не знаю как три сразу взять. Знаю как только два

Цикла достаточно одного. Но брать из списка надо три элемента, идущих подряд. Можно использовать срез для простоты. x, y, z = s[i:i+3]

TC, уберите, пожалуйста, из вопроса задачу: она к вопросу не имеет отношения. Картинку с кодом замените на код текстом, у нас не принято код картинками вставлять. Код, который вы привели, к задаче мало относится, но с этим, вроде, ничего не сделать, иначе бы вы не задали вопрос.

triples перебирает тройки подряд идущих элементов из последовательности:
def triples(seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    for a in it: break
    for b in it: break
    for c in it:
        yield a, b, c
        a, b = b, c


r = range(10)
for t in triples(r):
    print(t)


$ python triples.py
(0, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 4)
(3, 4, 5)
(4, 5, 6)
(5, 6, 7)
(6, 7, 8)
(7, 8, 9)


P.S. for a in it: break хочется заменить на a = next(it), но вторая конструкция сломается на пустой последовательности seq, а первая её правильно обработает. То же самое для следующего for b in it: break и последовательности из одного элемента.
P.P.S. tuples позволяет вернуть кортежи любой заданной длины k:
def tuples(seq, k):
    it = iter(seq)
    ab = tuple(x for _, x in zip(range(k - 1), it))
    for c in it:
        yield *ab, c
        ab = ab[1:] + (c, )


r = range(10)
for t in tuples(r, 4):
    print(t)


$ python tuples.py
(0, 1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 4, 5)
(3, 4, 5, 6)
(4, 5, 6, 7)
(5, 6, 7, 8)
(6, 7, 8, 9)



Цикл for с break вместо просто next - это для красоты что ли, чтобы циклы друг под другом были? )

@CrazyElf, они обрабатывают последовательность короче двух элементов без ошибок. Добавил пояснение в ответ.

А вообще тройки перебирать проще всего через zip списка с самим собой, но со сдвигом:
s = list(range(10))
for x, y, z in zip(s, s[1:], s[2:]):
    print(x, y, z)


Красиво, но создает в памяти три копии одного и того же списка.

@VladimirBogdanov Да, питон тут отличился. В других языках бывает, что слайсы - это вьюхи, а не копия.

Меня тоже напрягает, что Питон постоянно пытается что-нибудь скопировать. Причем явно этим управлять сложно.

@VladimirBogdanov Ну потому что он скриптовый язык, а не язык, заточенный на скорость, как Golang какой-нибудь. Парадигма питона - стараемся не менять ничего "по месту", а фильтруем, сортируем, что-то делаем - создавая каждый раз новую коллекцию. Так надёжнее ничего не испортить случайно. Хотя по факту в питоне с этим всё-равно беда.

Решение на итераторах для не только трех элементов. В параметре quantity задается требуемое количество элементов. Вместо data подставьте итератор по файлу.
from collections.abc import Iterable
import itertools

def get_elements(data: Iterable, quantity:int):
    iters = (itertools.islice(data, i, None) for i in range(quantity))
    yield from zip(*iters)

data=range(5)
print(*get_elements(data, 3))

